# How to limit on # elements in array column and/or total size in Athena / Presto?

Tags: parquet, presto, amazon-athena

I've been looking at the Athena and PrestoDB documentation and can't find any reference to the limit on number of elements in an array column and/or maximum total size.  Files will be in Parquet format, but that's negotiable if Parquet is the limiting factor.

Is this known?

MORE CONTEXT:

I'm going to be pushing data into a Fire Hose that will emit Parquet files to S3 that I plan to query using Athena.  The data is a one-to-many mapping of S3 URIs to a set of IDs, e.g.

```
s3://bucket/key_one, 123
s3://bucket/key_one, 456
....
s3://bucket/key_two, 321
s3://bucket/key_two, 654
...
```

Alternately, I could store in this form:

```
s3://bucket/key_one, [123, 456, ...]
s3://bucket/key_two, [321, 654, ...]
```

Since Parquet is compressed I'm not concerned with the size of the files on S3.  The repeated URIs should get taken care of by the compression.

What's of more concern is the number of calls I need to make to Firehose in order to insert records.  In the first case there's record per (object, ID) tuple, of which there are approximately 6000 per object.  There's a "batch" call but it's limited to 500 records per batch, so I would end up making multiple calls.  This code will execute in a Lambda function I'm trying to save execution time however possible.

Comment: Are you facing any issue?

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any explicit limit from Presto/Athena side for number of elements in an array column type. Eventually it drills down to JVM limitation which will be huge. Just make sure that you have enough node memory available to handle these fields. Would be great if you can review your use case and avoid storing very huge column values (of array type)

Comment: I added some more context in the question body.  The choice is between big column values or ~6000x more rows.

Comment: As I said earlier, there is no limitation as such. Execute the job and see the appropriate node memory required. I've seen use cases where users are using large arrays.